# Border color change on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been trying to create a `border-color` change hover effect with CSS and something seems to not be working properly. Here is my code:

**Markup:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="hover">
    <img src="img/content/lighter.png" alt="lighter"/>
    <p>Discusing Strategy</p>
  </li>
  <li class="triangle"></li>
  <li class="hover">                  
    <img src="img/content/wrench.png" alt="wrench"/>
    <p>Beginig <br/> Designs &amp; Development</p>
  </li>
  <li class="triangle"></li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/content/car.png" alt="car"/>
    <p>Delivering Product</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#bpath ul li.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 95px solid  #d0dde5;
  border-left: 20px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-bottom: 95px solid  #d0dde5;
}

div#bpath ul li.hover:hover li.triangle {
  border-left-color: #5f9999;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I used the same technique to change the color of the `p` element and that worked. Why dosen't the border color change work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all triangle li's to be changed use this:

```
div#bpath ul:hover li.triangle{
                                border-left-color: #5f9999;
                            }
```

If you want just the next triangle element it's more tricky but you can try this:

```
div#bpath ul li:hover + li.triangle {
  clear:both;
}
```

I think this doesn't work on ie. If you want it to work on IE i would go for jquery.

Comment: Aldo the answer you provided wasent the one I was looking for the second selector seemed to have did the trick thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your selector:

```
div#bpath ul li:hover li.triangle
```

is trying to match a `li` element of class 'triangle' within an `li`. As you don't appear to have a nested list (therefore no `li` elements within other `li` elements) this doesn't seem able to work.

If you remove the latter `li` (`li.triangle`) to give (all, or one, of) the following:

```
div#bpath ul li:hover,
#bpath ul:hover li.triangle:hover,
#bpath ul:hover li.triangle,
#bpath ul li.triangle:hover {
    border-left-color: #5f9999;
}
```

this might work. Assuming your posted-HTML is correct.

Comment: the only problem is that only the li's with a class of triangle have a border aplied to them and I am trying to modify only the color to them while hovering on the other li's

Comment: So use the `#bpath ul:hover li.triangle` selector. As you didn't specify (or I couldn't tell) exactly what you wanted I had to guess a lot, hence the large selection of selectors. =/

Comment: I've aded a class of hover to the first and third li so you can see what I am trying to achiver I have already did this in my code and it still dosent work

Answer (score 0):

you should use this way,

```
div#bpath ul li.triangle:hover {
  border-left-color: #5f9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this fiddle, which changes the triangles color and adapt it to clarify your question. http://jsfiddle.net/j7YSu/1/

(or just accept it as the right answer :))

i had some issues with your code, but maybe this fiddle will help: http://jsfiddle.net/j7YSu/3/

Comment: I am not trying to change the color of the li with a class of triger while hovering on it I'm tryong to change it's color while hovering on another Item